# Sending mail with django newsletter

Tags: django, python-3.x, email, newsletter

I´m trying to use the [django_newsletter](https://github.com/dokterbob/django-newsletter) app and I can understand how it works. Some can helpe me please? Anybody has used any other module to sending emails like this?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I just wanna send an email, and want to know how it works... I don´t understand the documentation..

Comment: For example, I created -using admin from Django- a newsletter and want to subscribe me using a real interface and not the admin from Django... How can I do this... I was trying to get this: http://127.0.0.1:8003/news/noticias-2/subscribe/ but it doesn't work...